# Should internal library types be visible through my library's interface?

Tags: c++, opengl, interface

I'm writing a wrapper for OpenGL. OpenGL has many types that it uses( typedefs to make it more portable ), and would take a great deal of effort to hide this from my library's interface. It also seems as if this would take away from the portability if I, say, replace every occurrence of GLuint with an unsigned int.

However, Qt's OpenGL wrappers do just that. Is there anything wrong with doing this? Is there anything wrong with exposing these types through my interface?

The Qt file, as you can see a lot of the basic types such as GLuint and GLint are replaced with built in types( static_casts are used when sending these built in types to an OpenGL functions, but that defeats the purpose of the typedefs in the first place. )

[https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/3232682d3b04ff16806fd8c5ad36271876a7b419:src/gui/opengl/qopengltexture.cpp#L256](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/3232682d3b04ff16806fd8c5ad36271876a7b419%3asrc/gui/opengl/qopengltexture.cpp#L256)

Comment: If you actually look at opengls headers, you will probably notice that most of the typedefs are simply aliasing unsigned int or similar, therefore there should be no technical issue to using the type they are aliasing as long as you use the right types and remain consistent in using/hiding them throughout your API.

Comment: @Robadob They could be different types on different systems. If I'm using an unsigned int to hide GLuint, and on a particular system GLuint is defined as something that cannot be converted to an unsigned int( unlikely ), my library would break.

Comment: @Robadob They're defined like that on common platforms because on common platforms the specification happens to map to these simple types. But in principle, a `GLuint` is specified independently and one type can change while the other remains the same. I don't know how common a non-32-bit `unsigned int` is and how likely a size change for `GLuint` is. But if either happens, these wrappers have a problem (at least in theory; whether real programs *need* the full size is another issue).

Comment: @Ben I was following the assumption that you would be compiling your library for whichever platforms it is to be used on, hence using the aliased types should cause no problems as far as I can see.

Comment: @delnan His question specifies c++, so surely if someone were to compile against opengl using the gl.h header, which defs GLuint as unsigned int, then it would be compiled to an unsigned int, regardless of compiler or platform. I would have thought it's a really bad idea to write a wrapper for a library and not rely on users compiling against the same header/version of the library the wrapper was designed for?

Comment: @Robadob The `gl.h` headers are not the spec. The OpenGL API is specified in a cross-platform manner, as are the types is uses (e.g., a `GLint` currently is *always* 32 bit). In contrast, many details of types like `int` are at least technically platform- and compiler-specific.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a clearly right or wrong solution here. IMHO, it depends on what the goal of your library is:

- Your library makes the use of OpenGL easier and more convenient, but the clients of the library can still be completely aware that they are using OpenGL. If that's what you're aiming for, I don't think there's anything wrong with exposing the OpenGL types. To the contrary, if the clients will also make OpenGL calls directly, without going through your library, having separate types exposed by your library would make the use of your library much more awkward.
- You're building an abstraction layer that hides the use of OpenGL. The clients of the library will not know that they are using OpenGL. For example, you could create a DirectX implementation of your library, and the clients would not notice the difference. If this is your goal, you need to hide the OpenGL types. You can define your own types that match the size of the OpenGL types, for example using the `stdint` types (e.g. `typedef uint16_t BenUShort`), and expose those types in the interface of your library.

Comment: Qt's OpenGL library is the first one. It's obvious you're using OpenGL, but they still hide the types. Why?

Comment: Well, you would have to ask them. ;) It doesn't look like they use a consistent approach. The `QOpenGLTexture` hides the types. But `QOpenGLFunctions` does not: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html .

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Will there be any linking reasons I shouldn't expose the types? Will this force the users of my library to also link against Qt or OpenGL to use those types?